# How to auto increment in sub foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays

Here is the example code:

```
    <?php 
    $arr = array(
    array(
        'company' => array(
            'code' => 'ccd1',
            'name' => 'cnm1'
        ) ,
        'products' => array(
            array(
                'code' => 'pcd1',
                'name' => 'pnm1'
            ) ,
            array(
                'code' => 'pcd2',
                'name' => 'pnm2'
            )
        )
    ) ,
    array(
        'company' => array(
            'code' => 'ccd2',
            'name' => 'cnm2'
        ) ,
        'products' => array(
            array(
                'code' => 'pcd1',
                'name' => 'pnm1'
            ) ,
            array(
                'code' => 'pcd2',
                'name' => 'pnm2'
            ) ,
            array(
                'code' => 'pcd3',
                'name' => 'pnm3'
            )
        )
    )
);


echo "<pre>";   print_r($arr);      echo "</pre>";
$AI = 1;
foreach($arr as $value){

    $total_products =  count($value['products']);
    echo $AI++.".{$value['company']['name']} ({$total_products})<br />";

    foreach($value['products'] as $value2){
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$value2['name']."<br />";
    }
}
```

I don't know how to explain it, but what I want is to add auto increment in sub foreach loop, like this:

```
1.cnm1 (2)
    1.pnm1
    2.pnm2
2.cnm2 (3)
    1.pnm1
    2.pnm2
    3.pnm3
```

Comment: what is your expected output ..?

Comment: `<?php foreach($arr as $index => $value) { echo $index.' '.$value; } ?>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you can just use the `foreach` keys plus one. As another alternative, if this is just for presentation, just use ordered lists:

```
echo '<ol>';
foreach($arr as $ar1) {
    echo '<li>' . $ar1['company']['name'] . ' (' . count($ar1['products']) . ')</li>';
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach($ar1['products'] as $ar2) {
        echo "<li>{$ar2['name']}</li>";
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}
```

It'll number those items accordingly. No need for addition. Plus you can use CSS to style the list,

Comment: This is the best solution imho. EDIT : You could drop the  `as k1` part though

Comment: @DarkBee actually i changed my mind at the last second, was going to use plus one initially

Answer (score 1):

You can access the key/index of an foreach :

```
foreach($arr as $i => $value){
    $total_products =  count($value['products']);
    echo ($i+1).'.'.$value['company']['name'].' ('.$total_products .')<br />';
    foreach($value['products'] as $j => $value2){
        echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.($j+1).'.'.$value2['name'].'<br />';
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
$arr = array(array('company'=>array('code'=>'ccd1', 'name'=>'cnm1'), 'products'=>array(array('code'=>'pcd1', 'name'=>'pnm1'), array('code'=>'pcd2', 'name'=>'pnm2'))), array('company'=>array('code'=>'ccd2', 'name'=>'cnm2'), 'products'=>array(array('code'=>'pcd1', 'name'=>'pnm1'), array('code'=>'pcd2', 'name'=>'pnm2'), array('code'=>'pcd3', 'name'=>'pnm3'))));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";

$AI = 1;
foreach($arr as $value)
{
  $total_products =  count($value['products']);
  echo $AI++.".{$value['company']['name']} ({$total_products})<br />";
  $k = 0;

  foreach($value['products'] as $value2)
  {
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$k++.". ".$value2['name']."<br />";
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the question as you manual increment the counter

Answer (score 0):

This also worked for me:

```
foreach($value['products'] as $key2=>$value2){
    $AI2 = $key2+1;
echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$AI2.".{$value2['name']}<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
foreach($arr as $value){
    $total_products =  count($value['products']);
    echo $AI++.".{$value['company']['name']} ({$total_products})<br />";
    $sub=1;
    foreach($value['products'] as $value2){
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$sub++.'.'.$value2['name']."<br />";
    }
}
```